# WPF Multiline TextBox for large content

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, multiline

In a WPF application, I want to build a "Find in Files" output pane, in which I can stream large quantity of text, without re-allocating memory at each line, like the `TextBox` would do.

The WPF `TextBox` has a single `Text` property which stores a contiguous string.  Each time, I want to add content, I need to do `textBox.Text += "New Text"`, which is bad.

Ideally, that control would be virtual and require a minimum of resources, just for the visible lines.

I thought about using a standard `ListBox` with a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, but it does not allow Text Selection across lines.

(At each new line added, I want the control to update)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try a stack panel itself instead of the list box

Comment: @Timothy -- how would that allow text selection across lines?

Comment: For people who came across this question because they were finding that a frequently changing (in my case read only) text box had the characteristics of a memory leak, be sure to set UndoLimit to something other than it's default of -1. The default value of -1 for a text box will allow unrestricted growth of undo history.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you do not expect much more than ten-thousands of search results in your application, a TextBlock control or readonly multiline TextBox will suffice by far.

The TextBox class has an AppendText() method which should be fast enough for you.

If you need text highlighting / formatting then maybe you want to use RichTextBox.

Comment: Thanks codymanix, the MSDN doc says:
The AppendText method enables the user to append text to the contents of a text control without using text concatenation, which, can yield better performance when many concatenations are required.

Also after looking at the implementation inside .NET Reflector, the AppendText is exactly what I need.

Comment: There is a performance issue with this solution.  :(  The TextBox takes too much UI resources (CPU) when flooding the control with thousands of lines.  The TextBox is not virtual and does complex calculations at each AppentText() calls.  

I think we would need a control that does it's redraw & layout in a virtual manner, as the ItemsControl would do.

Comment: Keep in mind that the textbox could be storing each of your appends for undo operations. You might want to change the UndoLimit field on the textbox.

Answer (score 7):

If you have really large content, then unfortunately all the WPF textbox and similar controls are very slow. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449616/wpf-richtextbox-performance). You could use [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx) as a replacement.

Comment: Wow, that's really a great suggestion. AvalonEdit's `TextEditor`solved my problems when trying to put more than 65k characters into a `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered or tried the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) control?

Comment: We have tried, but the performance become disastrous, probably because of the overkill related to string formatting, which I don't need.

Answer (score -2):

A StringBuilder, just append the text to the String builder and instead of doing

```
textBox.Text += moreText;
```

do

```
myStringBuilder.Append(moreText);
textBox.Text = myStringBuilder.ToString();
```

This should take care of the [Schlemiel the Painter's](http://tinyurl.com/n8e2bt) algorithm.

Of course, the string builder should have to be a member of your class so it exists through your object's life span.

Comment: each time you call ToString() on the StringBuilder, it allocates a new contiguous string containing the concatenated strings.  Since I will be appending new lines to the control all the time, I exactly don't want that.

For each new line, I want the control to update.