# Getting and setting large amount of text data in clipboard

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, winui-3

I'm making simple tool app in C#, I have a textbox and I want to paste some text (around 300k lines), but this makes the app unresponsive. I waited like 10 minutes and nothing moved forward.

Is there some way to handle paste and copy operations on large data sets in smoother way? For example pasting and copying same amount of data in Windows Notepad takes just few seconds.

I use

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent()
```

and at this app hangs.
Example Code
`Xaml`

```
<Window
    x:Class="App2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer  Grid.Row="0"  Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Query Result" Text='{x:Bind pasteResult, Mode=TwoWay}' PlaceholderText="Paste results here" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`cs file`

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace App2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string pasteResult;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us some code?

Comment: @Kroepniek basically it just looks like this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.paste?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#examples without  calling `replace`

Comment: You might want to check if it is the clipboard or UI that takes a long time. 300k lines would be large, but just copying bytes should be fast, But not all UI controls will work well with very large amounts of text. See [this question about wpf rich textbox performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449616/wpf-richtextbox-performance)

Comment: @JonasH it hangs on `Clipboard.GetContent()` so i guess this is a clipboard issue.

Comment: this article might be of interest: [Is there a maximum size for Windows clipboard data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220608-00/?p=106727). Afraid that I cannot add much however.

Comment: I don't reproduce. What takes time in the code you relate is `addressBox.Text = singleLineText;` not `GetContent()` (and in fact it crashes with my example). Please provide a reproducing code and a sample file https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Simon i can remove this line and the same thing happens, i will provide code in a moment

Comment: @SimonMourier i updated question with code, but this is really simple template project with just a textbox added. Does not matter if i use Paste Event or just default event handler for textbox.

Comment: Ok, so this is quite different than what you said, in this mode you don't use Clipboard.GetContent(), you directly bind the TextBox element to the clipboard. Anyway I don't think it changes my point, the performance problem (which is real compared to notepad, but it works) is not caused by GetContent() nor the clipboard in general, but by gettting/setting the TextBox's Text value with a big sized text (and repainting  which goes through DirectWrite). You should report to Microsoft, maybe they can do something (not sure about that)

Answer (score 1):

As @Simon Mourier mentioned in the comments, the performance problem is not related to the clipboard, but the `TextBox` control processing that amount of data.

So, let me give you another option using the `ItemsRepeater` which comes with virtualization built-in. (In my laptop) it takes approx. 3 secs to show 500K lines of text from the clipboard.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="ClipboardTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                Click="PasteButton_Click"
                Content="Paste" />
            <Button
                Click="ClearButton_Click"
                Content="Clear" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="MessageTextBox"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsRepeater x:Name="TextItemsRepeaterControl" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

namespace ClipboardTests;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetTextLinesFromClipboard()
    {
        DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();

        if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text) is true)
        {
            string text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();

            string[] lines = text
                .ReplaceLineEndings()
                .Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.None);

            return lines;
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    private async void PasteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IEnumerable<string> lines = await GetTextLinesFromClipboard();
        this.TextItemsRepeaterControl.ItemsSource = lines;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        this.MessageTextBox.Text = $"Pasted {this.TextItemsRepeaterControl.ItemsSourceView.Count} items in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} s.";
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextItemsRepeaterControl.ItemsSource = null;
    }
}
```